# illegal activity on web

Tags: criminal-law

is having a website for the sell of prescription and illegal drugs illegal? If so how can they be caught if they are changing IP addresses every transaction? The only other thing I know is it is out of Texas and the drugs are coming from Mexico.

Comment: Well....... Finding the criminal is the work of police and not really a legal topic. This

Comment: There might also be a jurisdiction issue. Cyberspace isn't as clearly delineated as the real world. Whose laws make illegal drugs illegal?

Answer (score 1):

Selling illegal drugs is illegal - how you do it is irrelevant. Law enforcement has various means for dealing with cybercrime and I do not know the technicalities of how they do it but the can if they devote enough resources to it. The major difficulty is that identifying the perpetrator is only half the problem if they are in a different jurisdiction: catching perpetrators is hard enough without trans-national police and judicial cooperation.